# nested defaultdict: TypeError: first argument must be callable or None

Tags: python, python-3.x, types, defaultdict, python-collections

Truing to create a nested `defaultdict` to avoid having to write long code.

The final `defaultdict` should looks like this:

```
dd = {str:{str:{str:{[]}}}}
```

But when I try to append item into the list it returns `TypeError`:

```
dd = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict([])))

dd['something1']['something11']['something111'].append('something')
```

> ----> 1 dd = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict([])))
>
> ```
>      TypeError: first argument must be callable or None
> ```

Do you know where is the problem?

Comment: This shouldn't have variable depth. It has depth 3 and then there is a list at the bottom.

Comment: The innermost dict `{[]}` doesn't appear to be a dict. Or did I misinterpret the notation?

Comment: @MilanoSlesarik
The last defaultdict declaration should be a bit changed to `defaultdict(lambda: [])` or `defaultdict(list)`.

Comment: It is not a dict it is a list. The innermost dict should be defaultdict with list values.

Comment: The innermost dict {[]} contains unhashable type: 'list' You should have key value pair there.

Comment: @FedirAlifirenko Thanks I thought that the it is commonly instantiated this way: defaultdict([]) but it was defaultdict(list) or defaultdict(lambda: [])